# C++ pointers: dereferencing, assigning values, etc

Tags: c++, pointers

The questions I'm asking are very basic, but I'm trying to understand the behaviour of pointers in C++ by doing exercises in the compiler. So, for example, I start by declaring an int pointer *p and trying to ascribe it some values and print it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *p, i;
int main(){
    i=5;    
    p=&i;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is very clear and easy, right? But while I'm wondering why the C++ syntax works this way, I test another way of assigning a value to a pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *p, i;
int main(){
    i=5;    
    p=&i;
    *p=3;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, the result is different now. The question is, why this wouldn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *p, i;
int main(){
    *p=3;
    i=5;    
    p=&i;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I have to dereference the pointer first before assigning it a value, but direct assignment would not work without dereferencing?

Also, if in the second example I wrote I added another assignment:

```
int main(){
    i=5;    
    p=&i;
    *p=3;
    *p=6;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This would not change the value stored at *p (it would still be 3). I don't simply want to learn by memorising this pointer behaviour, I'm interested in understanding why it works this way. Thanks.

Comment: Where you are using `*p=3;` when `p` isn't initialized to a valid address, you have a sample for _'undefined behavior'_, no more no less.

Comment: OK, but why does it work (ie, *p gets assigned 3) if I do this after dereferencing p? Is it because this is the standard defined behaviour for assigning a value to a pointer?

Comment: What makes you think _'it works'_?!? Anything could happen, it's undefined. Your fridge may explode ...

Comment: " I'm trying to understand the behaviour of pointers in C++ by doing exercises in the compiler. " - this is a bad idea, because you have no way of knowing whether what you see is defined behaviour or undefined behaviour.  Learn by reading a book. K&R 2 is good for learning pointers in C. In C++ pointers should be used sparingly and left for a later stage of learning if you are a beginner.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for the suggestion, I don't think I have a choice, since pointers are part of my C++ course (pointers, pointers arythmetic, pointers arrays, etc). Even if it's a beginner course, pointers are used everywhere. There's a lot more stuff which is simply taught "as is" about C++, since they can't explain it in terms of defined behaviours.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible course and a good way to turn new students off the language. Anyway, C++ is not suited to trial-and-error learning; you must learn via a reference that you can trust to have correct code and explanation.  (SO posts are pretty good for that but you will get info in bits and pieces rather than a well presented story).

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *p, i;
int main(){
    *p=3;
    i=5;    
    p=&i;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work because you are trying to assign a value to the integer that `p` points to.  That's what this line does:

```
*p = 3;
```

That means, "store the value 3 at the location which p points at".  But `p` doesn't point at anything, because you didn't assign it to point to anything until two lines later.

```
p = &i;
```

That means, "assign the address of i to be the value of p". Or, in other words, "store the address of i in p".  `p` needs to point to something, before you can assign to the thing p points to. Otherwise you have undefined behavior.

On the last section:

```
int main(){
    i=5;    
    p=&i;
    *p=3;
    *p=6;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You say this: "This would not change the value stored at *p (it would still be 3)." -- I'm not sure why you say that. Yes, it would change the value stored at `*p` (which is the value of `i`). It changes it to 6.

Comment: OK, thanks. So a pointer cannot be assigned a literal directly? I thought this is possible.

Comment: @user3762829 you are not "assigning a pointer a literal". You are assigning a literal to *the thing being pointed to*.  Which does not exist because you have not made the pointer point anywhere.

Comment: @user3762829: Pointers store addresses of other objects. Dereferencing a pointer gets you the object it points to (i.e. the object which is stored at the address the pointer holds). But if you haven't given the pointer an address of a valid object, it is undefined behavior to try to dereference it.

Comment: @user3762829 I think your problem is that you're seeing `*p = whatever` as some kind of magic syntax. It isn't. `*` is an operator like any other. When you do `*somepointer` it gives you the object that is at the address stored in `somepointer`. So `*p = 3;` gets the object at address `p` and stores `3` in it. If `p` doesn't yet store a valid address (because you haven't given it one yet), you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Joseph - Yes, I got it. Basically the pointer needs to point to something to be able to actually store a value. It can't be an address to nowhere storing something.

Comment: @user3762829: *"Basically the pointer needs to point to something to be able to actually store a value."* -- That's the wrong language. A pointer pointing to something *is* the pointer storing a value. And that value is an address. An int pointer (`int*`), for example, does not store an int value. It stores the address of an int. When you say `*p = 3;`. You are not storing a value in `p`. To store a value in `p` looks like this: `p = &i;`.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, why this wouldn't work:

```
int *p, i;
int main(){
    *p=3;
```

here you attempt to dereference `p` and write something, but since `p` is uninitialized here (it can be 0, for example), you are trying to write to memory that you didn't allocate, thus this is a segmentation fault.

> Also, if in the second example I wrote I added another assignment: [...] This would not change the value stored at *p (it would still be 3).

Actually, it would. Why would you think otherwise?

> I'm interested in understanding why it works this way.

You're on the right track, just continue reading (e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)) and experimenting!